# Alternative to JavaScript's setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I need my contents to be shown in real-time, but when loading this many things it takes up so much CPU and is very laggy.

Is there an alternative to my code below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refresh_bal = setInterval(
        function (){
            $.get('./php/get_balance.php', function(balance) {
                $('.balance').html(balance);
            });
        }, 1000);

    var refresh_total = setInterval(
        function (){
            $.get('./php/get_total_bets.php', function(total) {
                $('.total').html(total);
            });
        }, 1000);

    var refresh_profit = setInterval(
        function (){
            $.get('./php/get_profit.php', function(profit) {
                $('.profit').html(profit);
            });
        }, 1000);

    $('.haa').on('click', function() {
        var refresh_bets = setInterval(
            function (){
                $.get('./php/get_bets.php', function(bets) {
                    $('.betsTable').html(bets);
                });
            }, 1000);
    });

    var refresh_site = setInterval(function (){
        $.get('./php/get_site.php', function(site) {
            $('.siteStats').html(site);
        });
    }, 1000);

    var refresh_client = setInterval(function (){
        $.get('./php/get_client.php', function(client) {
            $('.clientShow').html(client);
        });
    }, 1000);

    var refresh_server = setInterval(function (){
        $.get('./php/get_server.php', function(server) {
            $('.serverShow').html(server);
        });
    }, 1000);

    $('.ha').on('click', function() {
        var refresh_chat = setInterval(function() {
            $.get('./php/get_chat.php', function(chats) {
                $('.chats').html(chats);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't use setInterval, instead use setTimeout and a function. Consolidate those requests into a smaller number of requests.

Comment: the best part of node.js is that it's NOT a whole other language.  Its the same one you're using here--not that that's the solution

Comment: @programminginallston, I'm new to JS as is.

KevinB can you give an example?

Comment: @programminginallston Why are you telling him to use node.js ? Node doesn't have anything to do with his problem nor does it help him to solve this in any way. This is node's problem domain.

Comment: Two words: [***web sockets***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum He isn't, he's simply stating that node.js *isn't* a new language. He specifically says it's not a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 8):

There are two primary things you can do to improve the performance of your code without moving to websockets.

First, replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout` when dealing with recurring ajax requests. The reasoning for doing this is if you're using `setInterval`, the next may get sent before the previous finishes which can eventually crash the browser. Using `setTimeout`, you ensure that the previous is complete before you request the next.

```
(function refreshBalance() {
    $.get('./php/get_balance.php', function(balance) {
        $('.balance').html(balance);
        setTimeout(refreshBalance,1000);
    });
})();
```

Next, consolidate all of those requests into as few requests as possible, ideally one. This is because for each request you make, headers and cookies also have to be resent, and browsers do have a limit to the maximum number of concurrent http requests that can be sent to a single domain at a time. If said limit is reached, ajax requests will be delayed until the previous ones complete. This can also lock up the browser.

Comment: I did that, thanks.  But sometimes when I use setInterval or setTimeout, none of them show up.  Why is that happening?

Comment: You would have to debug that on a case by case basis. there are dozens of reasons it could not show up. The server could be returning something you aren't expecting, the network could be slow and timing out, a server error could be occuring, a js error could be occuring, maybe you have a logic error and the target element didn't exist when the request completed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function loop() {
  // do the logic here
  ...
  ...
  setTimeout(loop, 1000); //recurse
})(); // doesn't need to trigger the function.
```

Comment: How would this improve performance? The problem is the repetition of multiple AJAX calls without even waiting for the callback.

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming an html5 site, you can use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) wich is incredibly fast otherwise, you should use jQuery `$.when()` and `setTimeout`. Of course you can use websockets but if you're not familiar with it, here's a solution that should boost your performance.

```
$(function() {
    function refresh_bal(){
        return $.get('./php/get_balance.php', function(balance) {
            $('.balance').html(balance);
        });
    }

    function refresh_total(){
        return $.get('./php/get_total_bets.php', function(total) {
            $('.total').html(total);
        });
    }

     function refresh_profit(){
        return $.get('./php/get_profit.php', function(profit) {
            $('.profit').html(profit);
        });
    }

    function refresh_site(){
        return $.get('./php/get_site.php', function(site) {
                $('.siteStats').html(site);
            });
    }

    function refresh_client() {
        return $.get('./php/get_client.php', function(client) {
            $('.clientShow').html(client);
        });
    }

    function refresh_server() {
        return $.get('./php/get_server.php', function(server) {
             $('.serverShow').html(server);
        });
    }

    (function refresh() {
        $.when(refresh_bal(), refresh_total(), refresh_profit(), refresh_site(), refresh_client(), refresh_server()).then(function() {
            setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
        });
    })();

        $('.ha').on('click', function() {
            var refresh_chat = function() {
                $.get('./php/get_chat.php', function(chats) {
                    $('.chats').html(chats);
                    setTimeout(refresh_chat, 1000);
                });
            };
        });

        $('.haa').on('click', function() {
            var refresh_bets = function (){
                $.get('./php/get_bets.php', function(bets) {
                   $('.betsTable').html(bets);
                   setTimeout(refresh_bets, 1000);
                });
            };
    });

});
```

**EDIT**

You can also do a single ajax call to a php that's include all your php files and echo a json containing all values.

```
$(function() {
   (function refresh() {
        $.getJSON('./php/op.php', function(data) {
            $('.balance').html(data.balance);
            $('.total').html(data.total);
            $('.profit').html(data.profit);
            ...
            setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
        });
    })();
});
```